# How to best restrict a fixed position DIV's height to prevent overlapping with the page footer

Tags: jquery, css-position

So I have a fixed position div whose contents must always stay at the same part of the page, however it is undesirable to have this `div.fixed` overlapping the `div.footer`. What jQuery might I use to manipulate the height of `div.fixed` to prevent it from overlapping the footer?

I'm assuming I'll need to deal with the fixed div in relation to the page or document vertical position, however I'm concerned about cross-browser implementations of this.

Here's a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8CYMn/4/ with an example showing the effect. If you scroll down you'll see the full width footer is overlapped.

Due to page container and z-index reasons, it's not really possible without considerable refactoring to place the footer above the fixed div in z-index.

**UPDATE**: Changed fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8CYMn/4/) to closer represent the issue I'm having. `div.fixer` has a gap at the top of the page, and also has a defined z-index that must be higher than the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8CYMn/2/

```
$('.footer').css({position:'absolute',top:$('.spacer').height()});
```

Comment: I think the reason your fiddle appears to work is that it places `div.footer` higher in the z-index than `div.fixed`. Unfortunately this is not ideal, I've updated my question with a more representative fiddle.

Comment: @DanH sorry but where do you see any z-index in http://jsfiddle.net/8CYMn/2/  ???  This is position:absolute; that is making difference, not z-index in example i provide

Comment: There is no z-index, however the default behavior is placing `div.footer` above `div.fixed` when you set it to absolute.